# 1kb partition: is it a problem, can it be removed?

Tags: hard-disk, disk

I have a 1KB partition on my drive, sda4. Here is the output of `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0   5.8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0    50G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 642.4G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Is there any reason for this? Can it be gotten rid of? Is it a potential problem?

Comment: If its 1kb then just ignore it. Partitioning some times result in data loss, you don't  wanna risk this for 1kb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mi casa, su casa

On my Ubuntu 14.04 system I have the exact same situation.

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   462G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   3.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Assuming the drive was partitioned using MBR, you can use `fdisk` to interrogate the drive further.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000df6c7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   968912895   484455424   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       968914942   976771071     3928065    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       968914944   976771071     3928064   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

So the 1K partition is an extended partition. So in this scenario, no, you cannot delete it.

#### Extended partitions

In an MBR partitioned HDD, an extended partition is a special partition which can contain logical partitions. In my case, `/dev/sda5` is a logical partition that's contained within the extended partition, `/dev/sda2`.

MBR has 2 types of partitions. Primary & extended. With an MBR style partitioning, you're only allowed 4 primaries. By utilizing extended partitions, you can increase the number of partitions allowed, above that limit.

#### Why?

I have no idea why Ubuntu does it this way. As far as I can remember, I went with the default options when I set that system up, so it's just how that particular distro opted to do it.

In Fedora, they do things with an [LVM - Logical Volume Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)), for example:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                      8:2    0 465.3G  0 part 
  ├─fedora_greeneggs-swap 253:0    0   7.7G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─fedora_greeneggs-root 253:1    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  └─fedora_greeneggs-home 253:2    0 407.6G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                        11:0    1 233.3M  0 rom
```

Here Fedora defaults to setting up 2 partitions. 1 for `/boot`, and another for everything else. Within that single partition, logical volumes using LVM are used for the various partitions, `/`, swap, and `/home`.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0000ccbe

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048   976773119   487873536   8e  Linux LVM
```

#### References

- [MBR - Master Boot Record - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)
- [LVM - Logical Volume Management - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management)